# Lie Derivative of Connection 1 form

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, vector-bundles

On Page 106 of Kobayashi & Nomizu's 'Foundations of Differential Geometry', the authors write

\begin{align*}
(L_X \omega)(Y)&=X(\omega(Y))-\omega([X,Y]).
\end{align*}

Here, $\omega$ is the connection one form and $X,Y$ are vector fields on the principal bundle $P$.

I am just wondering how they arrive at this equation and how to interpret the quantity $X(\omega(Y))$ since $X$ is a vector field in $P$ and $\omega(Y)$ is a vector field in $\mathfrak{g}$ - the Lie algebra of the structure group $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the Leibniz rule for the Lie derivative - this is more clear if you rewrite it as $$L_X ( \omega (Y) ) = (L_X \omega) (Y) + \omega( L_X Y).$$

Since $\omega$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued 1-form on $P$, $\omega(Y)$ is just a function $P \to \mathfrak{g}$. Since $\mathfrak{g}$ is just a vector space, we can simply take the componentwise derivative of  $\omega(Y)$ in the direction $X$ to get $X(\omega(Y))$.